# HTTP POST read response as regular string

Tags: c#, .net, web

I am currently doing a API HTTP POST project.
I should be getting

```
"[{\"ID\":\"311d1977-4772-435a-92aa-028791c53154\",\"ParentID\":\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\",\"Type\":\"txt\",\"OwnerID\":\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\",\"Name\":\"Davinshi.txt\",\"CreatedBy\":\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\",\"CreatedDate\":\"2015-06-05T04:11:33.187\",\"Status\":0,\"Mark\":null},{\"ID\":\"25c80f4e-679c-4093-ade9-0b99da480153\",\"ParentID\":\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\",\"Type\":\"jpg\",\"OwnerID\":\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\",\"Name\":\"leonid afremov.jpg\",\"CreatedBy\":\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\",\"CreatedDate\":\"2015-06-05T04:11:46.61\",\"Status\":0,\"Mark\":null}
```

However with the follow code I am getting a weird output

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var val = new NameValueCollection();
                foreach (var item in values)
                {
                    val.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }

                var response = client.UploadValues(url, val);

                return Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
            }
```

This is the output

```
\"[{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"311d1977-4772-435a-92aa-028791c53154\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Davinshi.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:33.187\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"25c80f4e-679c-4093-ade9-0b99da480153\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"leonid afremov.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:46.61\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"5648cc67-1408-4935-a656-0f9b5116db8d\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"misty mood leonid.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:49.437\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"7402e7b8-1ec4-4bf8-9042-142a69cecbcd\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"winter sparkle.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:12:03.26\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"7159e926-1601-41d6-8dce-20e5daab90a6\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"gentle rain beata sasik.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:40.6\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"e61f7bc4-bebf-403b-a478-22b36856a6df\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"MoonLight.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:50.797\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"e46e6250-655b-4105-a888-2574750f2944\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"blue fire.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:27.037\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"bfca703b-1720-4a67-b0a4-2f6146c820aa\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":null,\\\"Type\\\":\\\"folder\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"School\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:17.96\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"5c1bf9ca-b368-46c8-9804-3254eda00806\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Woman.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:12:06.607\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"8ad07f3c-7a57-4add-92c0-329aca372c8b\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"intimacy worship.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:40.727\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"ac5384c4-66ca-45cd-99f0-437c0789a26a\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Under the Rain.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:12:01.007\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"aa731f04-cc4e-4349-9268-4476ff04b473\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"bfca703b-1720-4a67-b0a4-2f6146c820aa\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"folder\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Marsiling Secondary School\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:20.983\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"af650810-0538-432e-8bf3-47429eb17d27\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"finger paintings.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:35.65\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"ddac31de-2b67-4f56-aefd-508a8f49926f\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"My Love.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:56.55\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"f2454474-d834-4bd1-992e-548cdc2734c1\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"boat.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:28.813\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"e1f5be01-29c7-4ca9-ae6f-5ddf8638cc67\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Davinshi.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:34.687\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"ff3a7365-7b4e-4a46-b545-6a2f889ff898\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"landscape paintings.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:44.48\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"327bf043-1e88-4265-ba5e-6de8394a0d84\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"lord rama.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:47.753\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"1d8a01de-da06-466d-8b7d-6e0bb8478d5e\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"intimacy worship.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:41.617\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"f23103ec-0d8c-407b-9f20-719f0577c274\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Coast of Sicily.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:32.187\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"374779d5-16e9-417f-808f-87fcf85035b0\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"misty mood leonid.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:54.203\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"f0bb2dc7-eac3-407d-a85a-886aaf161fc2\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"boat.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:28.907\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"607ee7b8-7287-4f3f-9867-8a8069562d3c\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"jpg\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Ballet.jpg\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:24.167\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"246b349e-ab32-407a-90ff-8df18bbabc68\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Ballet.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:23.917\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"Mark\\\":null},{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"457d722f-a675-4523-bd83-8f309dcd254e\\\",\\\"ParentID\\\":\\\"187a064e-ffea-45a2-9264-9acecff911e1\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"txt\\\",\\\"OwnerID\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"finger paintings.txt\\\",\\\"CreatedBy\\\":\\\"5bd087f0-070d-48bd-98b4-10ffa4b3b792\\\",\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2015-06-05T04:11:39.017\\\",\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\
```

Which I think the HTTP POST Response is reading the string as a verbatim string.
Any idea how can i fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the data as it is and not the C-escaped things that the debugger likes to show? There is no such thing as a "verbatim string" outside the C# sources.

Comment: the `json` you posted is not valid.

Comment: Yeah. Because in string " \" " = @" " ". Any idea how should I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the API will automatically convert the object to json format.
The problem occur when I try to serialize the object before sending trough the API.Hence, like what Denis Yarkovoy said. It's double serialized.

Answer (score 2):

When I run your code, the output of `Encoding.Default.GetString(response)` is exactly the string you posted at the top of your question.

The excessively backslash-escaped string appears in the Visual Studio debugging window simply because VS escapes special characters when displaying a string, but if you try to save this string into a file or use it in any other way in your code, you will see that only the double quote marks are escaped, like the string at the top of your question.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I cannot de-serialize the string

Comment: Can you de-serialize the string on top of your question? If so, what utility do you use for de-serialization?

Comment: yeap. I can de-serialize with the string on top. I am using Newtonsoft.Json for serialization .

Comment: Here is the code I tried:
 using (var client = new WebClient())  {
                var val = new NameValueCollection();
                var response = client.UploadValues("http://syf2015-api.azurewebsites.net/File.svc/GetAllFile", val);
                var s= Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
                var unescapedString=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
            }

runs without issues on my end and unescapedString contains valid JSON string -  [{"ID":"311d1977-4772-435a-92aa-028791c53154" …. cant paste the full string due to limitations in comments

Comment: It appears that you need to apply de-serialization twice. The first time, deserializer un-escapes double quotes and returnes unescaped string that becomes a valid JSON. When you de-serialize it again, you will get an object containing arrays, values and properties encoded in your string

Comment: Yeah . But any idea how should I do it ?

Comment: Sure, here is the code: var unescapedString=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.Default.GetString(response)); var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(unescapedString);